# Why do i keep getting operation not permitted?

Tags: android, permissions, selinux

On my android 8.1.0 system, i try to write directly to a block device.
(partition on emmc)

I can write to P24, but not to P25 somehow, and i can't figure out why.
There is nothing in logcat or dmesg logs.
No avc: denied.

```
# whoami
root

# ls -lZ mmcblk1p24 mmcblk1p25
brwxrwxrwx 1 root root u:object_r:block_device:s0 259,   8 2011-11-11 11:11 mmcblk1p24
brwxrwxrwx 1 root root u:object_r:block_device:s0 259,   9 2011-11-11 11:11 mmcblk1p25

# dd if=/dev/zero of=mmcblk1p24 bs=1 count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1 bytes transferred in 0.001 secs (1000 bytes/sec)

# dd if=/dev/zero of=mmcblk1p25 bs=1 count=1
dd: mmcblk1p25: Operation not permitted
1+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes transferred in 0.001 secs (0 bytes/sec)

# busybox lsattr mmcblk1p24 mmcblk1p25
lsattr: reading mmcblk1p24: Not supported
lsattr: reading mmcblk1p25: Not supported
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it.
The block device had the ioctl BLKRO bit set

```
# blockdev --getro /dev/block/mmcblk1p24
0
# blockdev --getro /dev/block/mmcblk1p25
1
# blockdev --setrw /dev/block/mmcblk1p25
# blockdev --getro /dev/block/mmcblk1p25
0
```